# py2exe: Reduce size of the library archive

Tags: python, py2exe

I just created my first py2exe executable and noticed that with the EXE, there is a ZIP file created with the size of around 1.4 MB.

My question is, can I reduce the size of this or is it expected that the typical size of an EXE generated with py2exe will be ~ 4 MB (that means with all the files: python2.6dll, library.zip)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer to your size reduction question is yes. Long answer I am not going to provide here, but instead direct you to py2exe's [OptimizingSize](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/OptimizingSize) wiki page.

I hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 3):

After changing those setup.py parameters i also run [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) on DLLs and executables and repack library.zip  with 7-zip, works well.

By the way, there is a page on the [wiki](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/BetterCompression) about using UPX and 7-zip.